# React Native: useState() does not change instant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want my function to update the `userIngredients` instant so I can work with it after rendering the screen.

```html
async function getUserData() {
    var userData = await firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).get();
    var labels = []
    userData.data().ingredients.forEach(ingredient => {
      labels.push(ingredient.label)
    })
    setUserIngredients(labels)
    setUserRecipes(userData.data().recipes)
    console.log(userIngredients)
  }
```

`userIngredients` are empty that's why my fetch won't work. so how can I fix this?

Comment: Where is user.uid coming from?

Comment: instead of console.log(userIngredients) try console log it within a separate „useEffect(() => console.log(userIngredients), [userIngredients]);“ after your „getUserData()“. Because state changes are async, you won‘t be able to grab it synchronously

Answer (score 0):

setState() is asynchronous. That means you won't be able be getting the data on userIngredients state on the same render where you changed it's value. To get the value you need to wait for another render.

If you don't want to render the screen when your data is empty. Use conditional rendering like:

```
if(!userIngredients) return <Spinner/> // or some loading component
return (<Actual Screen/>)
```

Comment: an how do i make a new render without just saving the file ?

Comment: thats what i have but now i need it to render one more time but how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```html
async function getUserData() {
    var userData = await firebase.firestore().doc("ingredients/" + user.uid).get();
    var labels = await userData.data().ingredients.map(({label})=>label)
    setUserIngredients(labels)
    setUserRecipes(userData.data().recipes)
    console.log(userIngredients)
  }
```